# Is Mongodb ObjectID unique between documents?

Tags: mongodb

Lets consider an example of blog site where I want to save questions and replies in two different documents. I know this can also be done with `Embedding` documents but lets assume we want two different documents.

And I have `Like` option on both question and reply. If user likes a question that particular `question's objectID` is stored inside a `Like` document and similarly for likes in reply.

Now I wonder whether the `objectID's` that I store in `Like` documents could create a conflict. Like if the `question's objectid` is `same` as any `reply's objectid`. IS it possible to have such conflicts??

In Mongodb `ObjectID` documentation the following is provided:

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
>
> a 3-bytemachine identifier,
>
> a 2-byte process id, and
>
> a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unique for all practical purposes. The non- uniqueness mentioned is a rather theoretical one.

The [ObjectId is constructed](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/#overview) out of

- a time stamp (seconds since epoch)
- a machine identifier
- the process id
- and a 3 byte counter starting with a random value *each second*

So, at median, unless you write in excess of 3080 documents per second per client, you should be safe.
It is to note that `_id` has an unique constraint: Even *if* you'd try to write the same ObjectId twice, there'd be an exception.

Side note: even hash algorithms like MD5 or (to a lesser extent) SHA256 have a slight chance of collision. But with a unique constraint, you are safe.

**Edit**: Since an exception is thrown in the very, Very, VERY rare case that two identical ObjectIds are generated and tried to be written concurrently, you simply handle them by generating a new ObjectId and try to save the document again.

Comment: Now my actual question is that if two documents are written concurrently...will they both have same objectID.. Or mongodb handles that too..

Comment: If two docs are written concurrently * with the same ObjectId* which is very, Very, VERY rare (probability less then winning the lottery three times in a row, iirc), an exception would be thrown, which you could easily handle.

Comment: thanks very much. This is what I was looking for. Will you please update your answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), it is most likely unique, not unique.

Comment: No, generation of ObjectId as such have nothing to do with documents.

Comment: then i think its not a good idea to use mongodb generated id. What are your suggestions??

Comment: What is the purpose of using the ObjectId. If you want to use them as "not natural" primary key then it may be fine. For practical purposes they will be unique and obviously if they are not unique then you will get an error.

Comment: i m using them as primary key