# Is primary keys in mongoDB unique in all database?

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering if the primary key is unique in all database I mean that there is no other id with the same value in another collection.

Comment: Like with GUIDs, they are **likely** to be unique when generated. There is a very small chance of generating a duplicate ID. See the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid).

Comment: Since you can manually specify an `_id`: no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Mongodb ObjectID unique between documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958919/is-mongodb-objectid-unique-between-documents)

Comment: @VanPeer  Seems really close to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no there are not!
even when The ObjectId is constructed out of

a time stamp (seconds since epoch)
a machine identifier
the process id
and a 3 byte counter starting with a random value each second

since you can create manually there is a chance!

I found this reply rathher good! and I quot by Markus W Mahlberg : 
Side note: even hash algorithms like MD5 or (to a lesser extent) SHA256 have a slight chance of collision. But with a unique constraint, you are safe.
Since an exception is thrown in the very, Very, VERY rare case that two identical ObjectIds are generated and tried to be written concurrently, you simply handle them by generating a new ObjectId and try to save the document again.